# Update Model and Display Updated Data in html table

Tags: html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple MVC application in which I am displaying data from the controller. and I want to show new data derieved from the call to the controller method.In other words, I am setting some default data to the html table and I want to change it using an Ajax call on button click. How can I do this, I can Share the code as follows :

The Model is :

```
    public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }

    }
```

The Controller is :

```
public class SendAjaxParameterController : Controller
{
    // GET: SendAjaxParameter
    public ActionResult GetTheData()
    {
        List<Employee> Employee_Details = new List<Employee>();
        Employee_Details = DefaultValues();
        return View(Employee_Details);
    }
    public List<Employee> DefaultValues()
    {
        List<Employee> Employee_Details = new List<Employee>();
        Employee emp = new Employee
        {
            Name = "John",
            Surname = "Doe"
        };
        Employee emp1 = new Employee
        {
            Name = "Mary",
            Surname = "Addinson"
        };
        Employee_Details.Add(emp);
        Employee_Details.Add(emp1);

        return Employee_Details;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Ajax_GetParameter(string name)
    {
        string nameofEmp = name;
        List<Employee> Employee_Details = new List<Employee>();
        if (name == "Monica")
        {
            Employee emp = new Employee
            {
                Name = "John",
                Surname = "Doe"
            };
            Employee emp1 = new Employee
            {
                Name = "Mary",
                Surname = "Addinson"
            };
            Employee_Details.Add(emp);
            Employee_Details.Add(emp1);
        }
        else
        {
            Employee emp = new Employee
            {
                Name = "Robert",
                Surname = "Doe"
            };
            Employee emp1 = new Employee
            {
                Name = "Monica",
                Surname = "Addinson"
            };

            Employee_Details.Add(emp);
            Employee_Details.Add(emp1);
        }
        return Json(new { success = true, data = Employee_Details },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

The View is :

```
    @model IEnumerable<datatableViewTocontroller.Models.Employee>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetTheData";
}

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>GetData</title>
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Scripts/datatable/DataTables-1.10.20/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    @section Scripts{
        <script src="~/Scripts/datatable/DataTables-1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/datatable/DataTables-1.10.20/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            var nameValue = "";
            var dttable = $("#mytable").DataTable();
            $("#btn_GetData").click(function () {
                if (confirm("Do you want to continue?")) {
                    nameValue = "Monica";
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/SendAjaxParameter/Ajax_GetParameter",
                        data: '{name:"' + nameValue + '"}',
                        contentType: "application/json; utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.success) {
                                alert(data);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    nameValue = "Not Monica";
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/SendAjaxParameter/Ajax_GetParameter",
                        data: '{name:"' + nameValue + '"}',
                        contentType: "application/json; utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
    }
</head>
<body>
    <div id="table-div">
        <table id="mytable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Surname</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var modeldata in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@modeldata.Name</td>
                        <td>@modeldata.Surname</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <br />
    <button id="btn_GetData" style="float:right;">GetData</button>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: I have Updated the Code and now it is returning the values in the data in the form of object.]

So, The question is How can I assign new data to the table ? Please Help!

Comment: what is op of `data` add that as well in your question

Comment: I didn't get that...Can you please ellaborate?

Comment: What does ajax return back i.e under success function. Do `alert(data);` inside ajax success function and see.

Comment: It is not returning anything...and I think it is not getting success becase, not even showing the alert with message successful

Comment: I have Updated the code and now it is returning values into the data in the form of json object. alert is now showing [Object][Object]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `each` loop to iterate through your json data which you have recieve from server and then use `+=` to append new row to some variable.Then to add these row to your `tbody` you can use `.html()`.

**Demo Code** :

```js
//your response
var data = [{
  "Name": "abc",
  "Surname": "xyz"


}, {
  "Name": "abcd",
  "Surname": "xyzd"

}]
var html = "";
//loop through data
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
//append row
  html += '<tr><td>' + value.Name + '</td>' + '<td>' + value.Surname + '</td><td><button name="edit">Edit</button></td></tr>';

});
//add row to tbody
$("#mytable tbody").html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table-div">
  <table id="mytable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <!--data will come here--> 
      <tr>
        <td>@modeldata.Name</td>
        <td>@modeldata.Surname</td>
      </tr>
     
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: if you notice there is one line which makes my normal html table to jquery datatable. the line is : var dttable = $("#mytable").DataTable();   the code you written is working fine as we are displaying the values from the response.But, when I try to search anything from the datatable it is not working as expected it is searching the value from the model values which was assigned at the first place.

Comment: @ajinkya check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/c6q5h98f/1/)

Comment: Ok! I'll try it and let you know 

Comment: Its not working its just skipping first record and showing all remaining records

Comment: There are no errors as such but the code behaviour is not correct...and I can see the logic is correct in which you are creating html table and destroyed previous datatable to convert the newly created html table into the DataTable. Somthing must be missing.

Comment: Yes .. I have added <tbody> tag inside for loop ..that should be outside for-loop . Both opening and closing tag of <tbody> .Here is [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/c6q5h98f/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can rerender table structure using Jquery after Ajax success call.
Just make Table Td structure and append in the respective div.

e.g.

```
$('You Parent div').empty().append('new structure');
```

as per your answer I've updated the code like :

```
    $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "/SendAjaxParameter/Ajax_GetParameter",
               data: '{name:"' + nameValue + '"}',
               contentType: "application/json; utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
               success: function (data) {
                        if (data.success) {
                        alert(data);
                      
                         var len = data.length;
                         var txt = "";
                         if (len > 0)
                         {
                             for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
if(i==0){
txt +="<table id='mytable'>" +
                                    "<thead>" +
                                    "<tr>" +
                                    "<th>Name</th>" +
                                    "<th>Surname</th>" +
                                    "</tr>" ;
}
                               txt += "<tr><td>" + data[i].Name + "</td><td>" + data[i].Surname + "</td></tr>"
                             }
                             if (txt != "") {
                                $("#mytable").empty().append(txt).removeClass("hidden");
                             }
                         }
                                    
                       }
                     }
                 });
```

Comment: But I want to remove previous data which is present in the table and assign newly arrived data.

Comment: Hence  i used the empty()

Comment: Yes yes I got it! I'll try this one.

Comment: I have edited your answer and it is not giving me the correct output

Comment: i have modified your code.  i can not review as i have less number of reputation.

Comment: Yes, it is appearing  now. Ajinkya please check the code as i did some correction.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only problem is to clear the previously loaded data. You can clear the `div` retaining that data and then load the retrieved data using jQuery:

```
$('#div-or-row-id').html(""); //Clear div
```

On the other hand, you can also try the following approach or replace the table data by setting table data by response of AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    //code omitted for brevity
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        SetData(data);
    },
    error: function (data) { onError(data); }
});

function SetData(data) {
    $("#div-or-row-id").html(data); // HTML DOM replace
}
```

Comment: Afterwards, I want to add a column of buttons which allow me to edit that row.

Comment: @ajinkya You can also insert the button by setting `innerHtml` property of the corresponding div.